# Why can't I connect to that site with webclient

Tags: .net, webclient

I can't connect to that site using the internal object webclient: 
http://mumbrella.com.au/freelancers

Can anyone tell me why?
Is this some kind of protection? I mean: webclient allows me to connect to billions of sites, why not this one?

Thanks.

PS: I work with VB.NET and winforms

Update: 
here's the code I use, it's a typical and simple webclient connection:

```
Private Sub connectWithWebClient(ByVal url As String)

    Try
        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

        html = client.DownloadString(url)

        client.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: show code, show what goes wrong

Comment: Just taking a quick look in Chrome dev tools. The HTTP request gets a 307 status code with a temporary redirect to the HTTPS version. Other than that, please add code so we can see where it's going wrong?

Comment: Thanks! I've just added that simple code which normally works.

Comment: Could you also show how it doesn't work. I'm guessing that `html` is either null or empty.

Comment: if it doesn't work, I can't show anything. html is empty.

Comment: https://kb.sucuri.net/firewall/signatures/bnp003 so they don't believe in the open internet (lol)